# iOS 5.1.1 memory management without Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have some strange problems of memory management on iOS 5.1.1, I'm NOT using Automatic Reference Counting in the project. Everything works well on iPad 3 5.1 or other devices with 5.1 or lower, this issue happens to two different project (one game and one app). So I think I have coded the right `retain`/`release` stuff.

Generally some Objective-C **objects are released before it should be**. When access it later, app crash. This happens on an iPad 3 LTE, an iPad 3 Wifi and an iPod Touch 4, all running iOS 5.1.1. It never happened on any device running iOS 5.1 or lower. I haven't found any pattern for this. Sometimes even an UIView which is still one the screen get released, if user touches a button, app crashes.

I understand these kind of issue can be debugged with `NSZombies`. But when I enable `NSZombies`, this kind of problem never happened.

It looks like a bug of iOS 5.1.1 to me, I'm wondering if it can be fixed on app side.

Comment: `But when I enable NSZombies, this kind of problem never happened.` Of course it doesn't crash with NSZombies, that's the whole point. NSZombies stops the app from crashing, and instead, it prints out a whole 'selector sent to deallocated instance' message in the console.

Comment: The problem is it does **not** "prints out a whole selector sent to deallocated instance' message in the console". Just nothing happened, app runes well with NSZombies.

Comment: Hmm. I think you should post some sample code that demonstrates the problem. Lots (most?) of us are using 5.1.1 and haven't seen this problem. You would have expected widespread crashing of apps in iOS 5.1.1 devices if your theory is correct, but instead it seems reasonably stable.